# Best practice for creating api models with database-generated fields?

Tags: java, api, spring-mvc

A little new to Spring, asking for best practices:

Say one of my model classes looks like this:

```
Entity
@Table(name="task")
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Task {


    @Id
    @NotNull
    private Long id; //this will be auto-generated in the database
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    private boolean completed;
    @Column(name="startdate", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMPTZ")
    private LocalDateTime StartDate;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMPTZ")
    private LocalDateTime deadline;
}
```

I have a standard DTO and Repository class for `Task`. But when I make the service class, the create method might like this (extremely simplified for illustration) :

```
  public Task create(Task t){
      try{
           return taskRepository.save(t);
      } catch(Exception e){
           //handle exception
      }
  }
```

So here's the thing: the parameter t won't have an id before the task is created in the database. But id is not supposed to be null. I see multiple options.

1. Create a `taskDetails` object with all the parameters except for `id` and `uuid`, and a similar object for all my other models. Maybe fragile because that's another class to change if I change Task.
2. The parameter t will be a Task with an id of 0. But will the `save()` method try to save it instead of letting the database create the value?
3. The create model will accept the parameters of Task as individual arguments as in `(String name, LocalDateTime startDate...)`. But I may not want to include all of the parameters so I'd need multiple create classes.
4. Let the `id` field be null.

This is a pretty common situation in any API, so I assume Spring has a standard way to do this. But I've been searching around and trying to find it and I can't. What is best practice here?

If this is a dupe, please direct me to the answered question.

UPDATE: Based on the answer by Shekhar I have researched and figured out that I should probably use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`, because that tells Spring that the db is taking care of generating the field. Presumably that means that I should get rid of the `@NotNull` annotation. But what if there are other fields that are auto-generated by the database? Can I use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` more than once?

Comment: maybe marking other fields which you do not want to persist as transient will help

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was use `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` for the identity, and for the other values used `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`. That means my java program was generating the identities, but that's okay because they were just random uuids so I set them to generate by default rather than always so if my program provided the uuid the db wouldn't complain.